# Google Sheets - Prevent autofill for single cell

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete, autofill

I am working in Google Sheets and 75% of the time, autofill is great. However it is occasionally disruptive.

An example:
I am working in a sheet and lets say I enter "Foot and Socks" in cell D5. Then I enter arbitrary info in cells E5 - G5 and press enter to go the next line. In cell D6 I want to enter just "Foot". Autocomplete recomends the "Foot and Socks" value from the previous line. Is there a shortcut I can use to tell the system "Do not use the autocomplete and tab to the next cell (E6)?" As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is enter an arbitrary character, then backspace to delete it before pressing tab to go the next cell in the row.

Normally, this isn't such a big deal but I'm doing this for about 1000 lines of fairly similar data and the few extra keystrokes are slowing me down and just frustrating in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off 'smart fill' (the aspect of the autocomplete functionality you are referring to) by going to Tools/Auto-complete and unticking 'Enable autocomplete'.